# pyplot is changing the color of the image

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib

I tried to plot some subplots using the code below. When i use OpenCv the image is fine, but when i use the pyplot, the color is changed.
Please see the images and the code.

[image]

Ploted with cv2

[image]
Ploted with pyplot

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(224)

ax1.imshow(img)
ax1.set_title('Original Image')



ax2.imshow(imgRedimensionata_proiect)
ax2.set_title('Alg image')

ax3.imshow(imgRedimensionata_traditional)
ax3.set_title('Traditional resize')

fig.show()
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like it's taking BGR and displaying it as RGB (or viceversa). Add something like this to fix it.

```py
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)       # get b,g,r
img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb
```

[reference](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_matplotlib_rgb_brg_image_load_display_save.php)

Comment: CV2 reads images as numpy arrays so you can also just address the colors in reverse, like `rgb_img = bgr_img[..., ::-1]`, should save some memory